# Importing data in R read.table and manipulating

Tags: r, vector, import

I would like to import data from a `*.txt` file that doesn't have a header.

Example:

```
123 25 585 M
185 89 58  F
898 55 233 F
...
```

And I want to add a header so I can manipulate it.

Here is my code :

```
    setwd("C:/Users/..")
readLines("matrix.txt",n=200)
data <- read.table("matrix.txt",sep=" ",header=F, col.names=c("X","Y","Z","sex") )
```

Now I want to manipulate each column, like for example X+Y ?

Comment: try `str(data)` to inspect the details of the file you just read in (should be a data.frame). `data$X + data$Y` will sum columns.

Comment: or is it possible to scan each column and set it equal to X ,Y ,Z ,sex

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But a data.frame is actually just a list of vectors. You can assign columns to new variables: `X <- data$X`

Comment: The sep= and header= values shown in the question are the defaults so they could be omitted.  `attach(data)` will allow you to access the columns as `X` instead of `data$X` but it is not recommended.   Also see `transform`, `with` and `within`.